# Getting only one record in writeHtml in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have retrieve data from mysql and putted it in html table and the result i stored in $tbl4 variable through concatenation but the problem is that i have multiple rows in my html table but when i use writeHtml() function of tcpdf it only print one record although the $table variabl contains all the rows and have tested it bye echo $tbl4.What problem with writeHtml function?

```
$tbl4='<table>


 <tr>
                 <td><b>Ingredient Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Function</b></td>
                 <td><b>%</b></td>
                 <td><b>Country Of Origin</b></td>
              </tr>';



            foreach($mArray as $item):
             $tbl4.='<tr>';
                  if($item['bold']):
                 $tbl4.='<td><b>'.$item['name'].'</b></td>';
                  else:
                 $tbl4.='<td>'.$item['name'].@$item['Baseid'].'<br>';
                     if(!empty($item['bvf'])):
                  $tbl4.='<div style="font-size:11px;text-align:right;">
                       Derived from:'.implode("<br>",$item['bvf']). 
                    '</div>';
                     endif;
                 $tbl4.='</td>';
                  endif;
                $tbl4.='<td>'.$item['type'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$item['total'].'</td>';
                   $COOL=$item['country']; 



                $tbl4.='<td>';

                  $array2 =  explode(',', $COOL);
                  $remain2=count($array2);
                  foreach ($array2 as $item2) {
                      $tbl4.="$item2";
                        if($remain2-->0)
                         $tbl4.= ', ';

                      }

                        //echo $item['Display'] 
                      $tbl4.='</td>';



          $tbl4.='</tr>';
                   endforeach;
          $tbl4.='</table>
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl4, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Comment: Will you please show how you are retrieving data from mysql. I think you have used `mysql_fetchAll()`  to retrieve instead of this please use `mysql_fetchAssoc()`

Comment: i have used mysqli assoc. i am getting data correctly from mysql and can easily display it by echoing it. but i think there is something wrong with writeHtml() that not displaying all the records?

Comment: while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):

Comment: are you trying to generate pdf file from HTML content??If so please use  `wkhtmltopdf` instead of tcpdf because I don't remember now when I was generating pdf file from tcpdf there was some rendering problem. If you would use `wkhtmltopdf` there will not be any rendering problem.

Comment: i have html file i want to convert it to pdf and store it in a directory on server can i achieve this through wkkhtmtopdf?

Comment: yes you can do . please ask another question I will explain you there

Comment: sir i have reached my question limit kindly if you explain it here will be great!

Comment: and i want to achieve this through php script as i have to run this script on my live server and generated pdf files need to be stored in directory on  the server as i told before.thanks

Comment: First install wkhtmltopdf on your PC using this link https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html.  If you'Re using docker just put  this code on your docker file `Run apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install --no-install-recommends wget && wget -nv -O /tmp/wkhtmltox.deb https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb && apt-get -qy install /tmp/wkhtmltox.deb
` and finally use it via composer following this https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-snappy